# a word for "switch on and off"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, verbs

I'm trying to say:

```
In simulations specific effects can be switched on or off to determine their impact.
```

This `switched on or off` seems to me rather clumsly. Is there a single verb with that meaning? I don't think `toggle` really works, but could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

How about **turn** on/off.
This verb is often used with effects as far as I can tell.

But that is two-word pairs. Sorry

Another variant is **enable/disable** )